# Running a boto3 script on multiple accounts all in different regions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cloud, boto3, devops

I am using an IAM user account to run a boto3 script against multiple aws accounts they are all in different regions. The default region for my IAM user in ~/.aws/config is us-east-1.. My script only works for the accounts in us-east-1 region but does not return anything for other regions. How do I get it to run cross regions?

Comment: You can specify region for each boto3 [session](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html) you need.

Comment: Each AWS account is in *all* regions (other than China and GovCloud (US) regions). Typically you can access all regions, unless your account/user has been setup to prevent you doing that. Which SDK call are you making and what are the results in regions other than us-east-1? Zero results? An error?

Answer (score 0):

IAM credentials are associated with a **single AWS Account**. If you wish to make API calls to another account, the program will either need credentials from that account, or it will need the ability to **assume a role in the other account**. That role would need to trust the IAM User/Role that are being used to call `AssumeRole()`.

(Some services, such as Amazon S3 and Amazon SQS, have additional access policies that can allow cross-account access without assuming a role.)

To connect to a specific **region**, specify the region when creating the client:

```py
  ec2_client_sydney = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
```